# Button with OnclickListener over Spinner with OnItemSelectedListener conflict Android

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-button

in my application I must to use a button over a spinner opened by the click on the button.  For open the spinner I use the code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            spinner.performClick();
        }
    });
```

And in the spinner I must use an ItemSelectListener:

```
spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    spinnerArray.add("EN");
    spinnerArray.add("PR");

    holder.spinnerLenguage.setAdapter(new lenguageSpinnerAdapter(
            convertView.getContext(), spinnerArray));
holder.spinnerLenguage
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                        int position, long arg3) {
...
...
...
}
```

But in my application the two events have problems, because button opens the spinner continuously and automatically selects the first item. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: nobody knows anything?

Comment: did you figure this out ?